# AngularJS - Directive formatter is not working for null value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Greeting. In my case, I can use formatter normally when the ngModel value (val at below) is not null. (< input > tag will be formatted.)

```
ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (val) {
    if (val) {
        console.log('log positive');
        return 'Record found';
    } else {
        console.log('log negative');
        return 'No record';
    }
});
```

That means the < input > tag will be formatted only while the val contain a value. However, I found that although 'log negative' shown, the < input > tag was not being formatted as well.

May I know if there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the full code of my usage

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="memberDetailCtrl" ng-init="ent.lastDepositDate=null;">
    <tit-date title="depositDate" ng-model="ent.lastDepositDate"></tit-date></tit-txt>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("memberDetailCtrl", function ($scope) {

})

.directive('titDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            fieldName: '@',
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<div><span>{{title}}: </span><input ng-model="ngModel" datepicker readonly /></div>'
    };
})
.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (val) {
                if (val) {
                    console.log('log positive');
                    return 'Record found';
                } else {
                    console.log('log negative');
                    return 'No record';
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please post your directive with calling. or post demo

Comment: @MaximShoustin I have updated the code in UPDATE 1. As you see in ng-init, I set ent.lastDepositDate=null and the formatter failed to format.

Comment: @mannok, the problem is likely with `datepicker`. If this is another directive, you need to make sure that it understands how to interpret a `null` value for `ng-model`. Alternatively, you can modify your `$formatters` definition to return the current date (i.e. `return new Date(Date.now())`) whenever `val` is `null` to avoid having to modify `datepicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Bros, finally I found that this is a bug in AngularJS 1.3.0. Once I upgraded it to the current version.